# Not able to a make a popover which gets triggered by clicking on the three dots like in facebook posts

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I have a list of posts in my django template and wants to put three dots on each post and want a popover to get triggered whenever I click on the three dots and the popover should have clickable options like Delete and Copy Link. You can have a look at instagram and facebook posts for a better idea. Thanks in advance.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div></div>
<a href="#" data-toggle="popover" title="Popover Header" data-content="Some content inside the 
popover"><span>&#8942;</span></a>

<style>
span {
  content: "\22EE";
}
</style>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
</script>
```

I tried this code but options are not clickable and also I am unable to display more than one options in the popover

Comment: You can do something like this: `$(document).on('click','.popover .popover-content',function(){})`

Answer (score 0):

At first I would recommend you to use a more current version of bootstrap if possible. At the time of writing that is bootstrap 5.

Want you probably want is not a popover, but a dropdown instead.
Maybe you should invest some time reading the bootstrap docs. Documentation about dropdowns you can find here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/dropdowns/

Your example in bootstrap 5 could look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Popover Example</title>

    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn-group dropend">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            &#8942;
        </button>
 
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Delete</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Copy Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But actually still the options are not clickable. If I click on "Some content inside the popover" nothing happens. Also how can I display multiple options in the popover like "Delete" and "Copy Link".

Comment: Now I understand what you want to achieve. bootstraps popover is only for displaying additional information. What you want is a menu or dropdown as it's called in bootstrap. I'll edit my answer.